# How to loop through columns in an oracle pl/sql cursor

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am creating a dynamic cursor and I would like to loop over the columns that exist in the cursor.    How would I do that?

For example:

```
create or replace procedure dynamic_cursor(empid in varchar2, RC IN OUT sys_refcursor) as
     stmt varchar2(100);
   begin
     stmt := 'select * from employees where id = ' || empid;
     open RC for stmt using val;

     for each {{COLUMN OR SOMETHING}}
       --TODO: Get this to work
     loop;
end;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to use [Oracle Dynamic SQL](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B10501_01/appdev.920/a97269/pc_13dyn.htm), most likely [method 4](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B10501_01/appdev.920/a97269/pc_13dyn.htm#1109).

EDIT:
Sorry, the above is for Pro*C. You will need to use the [DBMS_SQL](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_sql.htm#i996963) package. It's fairly complex, but will allow you to parse, execute, and fetch any arbitrary SQL statement you need, all at run time. In particular, have a look at examples 3 and 8.

Comment: I have the dynamic sql working.  My example code is oversimplified.  What I would like to do is have the stmt variable be much more dynamic, to the point where I would not be commited to a fieldset.  That is why I want to loop of the columns in the cursor.