# Comparing two tables with huge number of columns

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have searched through and didn't find a solution concerns so many columns to compare.

I have 1 large table (ruleTable) with ca. 300 columns and 1723 rows and another table (sampleTable) with 1 rows and exactly the same columns.
What I want to do is to write a procedure (with 2 arguments: sampleTable and ruleTable) comparing that 1 row from 2nd table with each row from 1st table.

The desired result is a table with 1723 rows and 3 columns: RULE_ID, WRONG(number of columns with the same value), RIGHT((number of columns with different values)

Till now I wrote a procedure (You can see it below), but it is definitely to slow, and it takes ages to finish the task. Have anybody an idea how to improve this approach (or maybe completely change) and cope with this problem? The largest problem is the number of columns...

```
PROCEDURE MAKE_CLASSIFICATION(sampleTable VARCHAR2, ruleTable VARCHAR2) AS
   l_query VARCHAR2(10000) := '';
   l_rulesColumns TEXTLIST := GetFeatureColumnList(ruleTable);
   l_rulesIDs TEXTLIST := GetTableColumnValues(ruleTable, 'ID');
   rule_value NUMBER;
   sample_value NUMBER;
   right NUMBER := 0;
   wrong NUMBER := 0;
BEGIN
   FOR j IN 1..l_rulesIDs.count()
   LOOP

      FOR i IN 1..l_rulesColumns.count()
      LOOP
         l_query := 'SELECT ' || l_rulesColumns(i) || ' FROM ' || ruleTable || ' WHERE ID=' || l_rulesIDs(j);
         EXECUTE IMMEDIATE l_query INTO rule_value;
         l_query := 'SELECT ' || l_rulesColumns(i) || ' FROM ' || sampleTable || ' WHERE rownum=1';
         EXECUTE IMMEDIATE l_query INTO sample_value;

         IF(rule_value = sample_value) THEN right:=right+1;
         ELSE wrong := wrong + 1;
         END IF;
      END LOOP;
      DBMS_output.put_line('right: ' || right || ';  wrong: ' || wrong );
      wrong := 0;
      right := 0;

   END LOOP;
END;
```

type TEXTLIST is global defined:

```
 TYPE TEXTLIST IS VARRAY(1000000) OF VARCHAR2(10000);
```

GetFeatureColumnList -> this function returns TEXTLIST with list of table colmun names (without 'ID' column)

GetTableColumnValues -> this function returns TEXTLIST with list of all values of a COLUMN (in our case - column 'ID')

Thank you in advance for your help friends.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use method 4 dynamic sql, to enable you to programatically loop through each column

see: http://www.oracle-developer.net/display.php?id=422

and [How to loop through columns in an oracle pl/sql cursor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2608475/how-to-loop-through-columns-in-an-oracle-pl-sql-cursor)

**or**

how about dynamically creating a single statement, using user_tab_cols
 then cross join your tables and add the results of each column comparison

....e.g.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE make_classification (sampletable VARCHAR2, ruletable VARCHAR2)
AS
   l_query          VARCHAR2 (10000) := '';
   right            NUMBER           := 0;
   wrong            NUMBER           := 0;
   l_number_of_columns NUMBER :=0;
   TYPE cur_typ IS REF CURSOR;
   c cur_typ;

BEGIN

    l_query:='SELECT ';
    FOR rec in (SELECT column_name FROM user_tab_cols  WHERE table_name=UPPER(ruleTable))
    LOOP
        IF l_number_of_columns > 0 THEN 
            l_query:=l_query||'+';
        END IF;    
        l_query:=l_query||'DECODE(t1.'||rec.column_name||',t2.'||rec.column_name||',1,0)';
        l_number_of_columns :=l_number_of_columns +1; 
    END LOOP;   

    l_query := l_query || ' AS cnt FROM '||ruletable||' t1,'|| sampletable || ' t2';

    --DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (l_query);

    OPEN c FOR l_query;
    LOOP
        FETCH c INTO right;
        DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('right: ' || to_char(right) || ';  wrong: ' || to_char(l_number_of_columns-right));
        EXIT WHEN c%NOTFOUND;        
    END LOOP;
    CLOSE c;       
END;
```

Comment: I think "need" is a little strong, but this is certainly a viable option

Comment: Isn't there a simplier method to do such a thing? Because, I tried to familiarize with '4 dynamic sql' and it is quite complex for me...

Comment: yes here your go, sorry about the formatting, but im on my phone at the moment

Comment: hmm, it's a solution, thanks. But I would like to have a "column-names-independent" procedure. Lets assume that we don't know the columns names, we can retrieve them for example with benefit of the GetFeatureColumnList function as an Array of VARCHAR2s. Any ideas?

Comment: see my update, you can build the select by querying user_tab_cols

Comment: I'm writing it now, and I didn't answer yet, because I have to check how fast this method is. But I have a feelin it is bull's eye. Thank you very much Kevin! I'll post the answer in several minutes.

Comment: Perfect!, this method is extremely fast. Thank you Kevin it was really smart ;-).

Answer (score 1):

If you're using 11g, I would look into using the UNPIVOT operator to turn your table with 300 columns into a view with 300 rows per entry (for a total of 1723*300 rows). Then use COUNT to determine the number of right and wrong answers. then you can PIVOT back so you have a right and wrong column.

Because you have so many columns, you could use a PL/SQL program to create the initial SQL query, but I wouldn't use dynamic SQL to run it every time.